# How to programmatically navigate in Android MediaBrowserService OnLoadChildren method

Tags: android, android-auto, mediabrowserservice

I have an audio app that runs on Android Auto that I would like to make more user-friendly for that specific use-case. Specifically, there are SETTINGS that the user should be able to modify through the AA UI and I've made that possible but it's a bit unwieldy.

Currently, what I do is, render a list of options for the user as MediaItems and modify the SETTINGS based on the options the user Taps, then re-render the options with the subtitle of the newly tapped option changed to signify that the application registered the tap.
But, this creates an extra entry in the navigation stack, requiring the user to execute an excessive amount of tapping of the BACK button (which is not only annoying but also causes AA to pop up the modal to make you stop tapping stuff for a bit).

My preference would be to use some sort of click/tap event/listener to modify the SETTINGS and refresh the current UI. Barring that, I'm wondering if there's some way to, in OnLoadChildren, programmatically navigate backwards to avoid requiring the user to do it. I'd even take being able to just catch the event and cancel the current navigation.

I'm open to any ideas about how to best handle this scenario.